# Text pushing down other text

Tags: react-native, react-redux

[Picture 1 (What I'm getting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au5NE.png)

[Picture 2  (What I'm getting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/551da.png)

[Picture 3  (What I'm getting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFE6b.png)

My problem is I want all text to be on the first line of each box I'm currently grabbing data from firebase-firestore in order to do this and (then want to be able to shuffle it but that is for later) then I want it to be in the middle of the box. Whenever I try to add padding or margins it pushes each text down instead of only pushing down or bringing up that one text line. I don't understand why this is happening if someone can help me that would be great! below you will find my entire code as well as my styling for it go crazy with it!

any help will be greatly appreciated!

(Sorry if the explanation is all over the place)

i'm kinda looking for something like this if it helps

[Picture 4 (What I am looking for)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVy1G.jpg)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, } from 'react-native';
    import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
    import firebase from 'firebase';
    import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


    const Reward = ({reward}) => {
      return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.item}>

            <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black', }}>{reward.Title1}</Text> 
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black' }}>{reward.Caption1}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{marginBottom:200}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }}>{reward.Title2}</Text> 
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black' }}>{reward.Points2}</Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'black' }}>{reward.Caption2}</Text>
            </View>

            <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }}>{reward.Title3}</Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black' }}>{reward.Points3}</Text> 
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black' }}>{reward.Caption3}</Text>
            </View>

            <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }}>{reward.Title4}</Text> 
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black'}}>{reward.Caption4}</Text>
            </View>

            <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }}>{reward.Title5}</Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black' }}>{reward.Points5}</Text>  
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black'}}>{reward.Caption5}</Text>
            </View>

            <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black',  }}>{reward.Title6}</Text> 
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'black'}}>{reward.Caption6}</Text>
            </View>

            </View>
            </SafeAreaView>


      );
    };
    const numColumns = 1;

    export default class RewardScreen extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection("rewards");
        this.unsubscribe = null;
        this.state = {
          rewards: \[\],
          loading: true,
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate)
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribe();
      }

      onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
        const rewards = \[\];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const {Title1, Title2, Title3, Title4,Title5, Title6, Caption1, Caption2, Caption3, Caption4, Caption5, Caption6, Points2, Points3, Points5, } = doc.data();
          rewards.push({ key: doc.id, doc, Title1, Title2, Title3, Title4,Title5, Title6, Caption1, Caption2, Caption3, Caption4, Caption5, Caption6, Points2, Points3, Points5,  });
        });
        this.setState({
          rewards,
          loading: false,
       });
      }

      // addRandomPost = () => {
      //   this.ref.add({
      //     title: 'Added Reward by random button',
      //     likes: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1),
      //     uri: `https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=${Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)}`,
      //   });
      // }

      render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
          return <ActivityIndicator size="large" />;
        }

        return (
            <View>
               <Header
      centerComponent={{ text: 'Rewards', style: {fontSize: 25 } }}
      containerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: 'whitesmoke',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      }}
    />
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.rewards}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Reward reward={item}>
            </Reward>
        )} 
        numColumns={numColumns}
            />

          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'flex-start', // if you want to fill rows left to right
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        marginTop: 10,
        alignSelf:'center',
      },

      item: {
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        borderRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 1.0,
        borderColor: 'black',
      }

          });
```

Comment: hey are you looking to make your text `center top` of the container ?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i'm looking for kinda like how picture number 4 looks like but without a modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `react native` you can try

`<View style={{ flex: 1,flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center',}}>`

Comment: change the justifyContent to alignItems and it works Beautifully! Thank you so much i can't believe i never thought of that!

Comment: `justify-content: longer word: horizontal alignment`

`align-items: shorter word: vertical alignment`

Answer (score 0):

create a `CSS` class for example :

```
.layout-view {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

and put it to your `View` component tag or wherever you want to align children texts like you want it. for example

`<View className="layout-view" >`

Let me know if it works, i will be happy to help further!!!

Comment: it's react native and it kinda helps but actually pushes down the text more which is odd